# gnuplot: How to keep windows terminal in background when calling from C++?

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot I can output the mouse position after a click with MOUSE_X and MOUSE_Y. I also found equations that should calculate fractional screen coordinates from them (in gnuplot help under gnuplot-defined variables). But that does not work for me, I get values > 1.0 and < 0.0.  Maybe it is because I am using splot, drawing a 3D surface? How can I do it in this case? Is there a gnuplot built-in way to get the screen x and y values?

Update with wider picture:
I feed gnuplot from a C++ program using a pipe. The data is a 3D surface for which the C++ program iteratingly calculates various points and plots these along with the surface in intervals of 1s. The purpose is to visualize the algorithm. So all data and calculations come from the C++ program, gnuplot is only for displaying the surface and points.
Now I would like to give an input into the program to control the program flow like stop the program, change some parameters of the surface or of the calculation. Currently I have a console where I can do inputs. For this I need to change the focus to the console and type in the right moment because the next plot action puts the focus back to gnuplot. So it would be more comfortable to do it from the plot. I thought to draw kind of buttons that you can click. When clicked the following user interaction like entering parameter values can be in the console if that is not possible with gnuplot.

Comment: I'm not aware that you can directly get screen coordinates, but you might be able to calcluate it from a 2D plot. I currently don't see how to get it from a 3D plot on a 2D screen. How should gnuplot know what is x and y and z if the mouse moves on a 2D plane? What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I feed gnuplot from a C++ program using a pipe. Now I would like to give an input into the program to control the program flow. Currently I have a console where I can do inputs but it would be more comfortable to to it from the plot. I thought to draw kind of buttons that you can click. Keyboerd input would also be ok but this did not properly work for me. Some keys are not accepted and it is not stable overall.

Comment: It's still not fully clear to me. Maybe it is a type of [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? Do you want to use C++ or gnuplot to control the graph output? Which gnuplot terminal are you using? What should happen if you click on a certain position (or button) on the canvas? What exactly did not work with keyboard input? Which keys are not accepted? Have you tried `bind`? Check `help bind`. Maybe you rephrase your question to include the bigger picture.

Comment: Ok, I did an update of the question, hope it is more clear now. Currently I use terminal windows.

Comment: Thanks for giving more context. I am not aware that you can give some interactive input (numbers, text) to gnuplot. And you have to pass it anyway back to C++ to change the calculation. Since you are controlling gnuplot via C++, isn't there a way with C++ to get the focus back to your console after plotting? I don't know if there is an option to run gnuplot only in the background without taking the focus.

Comment: Do you absolutely need an interactive terminal, e.g. for interactively rotating your graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `terminal windows`, maybe the following helps to avoid that the focus is on the terminal after plotting. I don't know if `wxt` or `qt` terminals have a similar option.

From `help windows`:

> **Bring to Top** when checked raises the graph window to the top after every plot.

So, try unchecking: Menubar | Options | "Bring to top"

At least when plotting or updating a plot from the gnuplot console, the focus will not go to the graph window. Maybe it does the same when plotted from C++. I don't know. Please test.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes it also works when controlling from my C++ program. Once I unchecked Bring to Top I can have tho console always in the foreground.